# Search Form refreshes the page instead of searching for a value

Tags: javascript, html

So my code is below.
Every time I try to search using the feature, it just refreshes the page. I have searched topics on here and still not been able to figure out how to stop it. I would really appreciate some help with this.

````
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="searchstands.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="searchstands.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            prepareSearch($('#searchBox'), {
              'searchLine' : '.searchTarget div.product',
              'searchSightPoint' : 'div.stand, span.apron, div.aircraft',
              'fade' : true, //true or false
              'contrastString' : false  //true or false
            });
          });
        </script>
<div class="row" id="standsearch">
            <form class="form-search" action="#standsearch">
              <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="span2 search-query" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="button" class="btnsearch">Find
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <center><div class="row">
            <div class="searchTarget">
              <div class="product span3">
                <div class="stand">
                  Stand 100
                </div>
                            <span class="apron">West Apron</span>
                            <div class="aircraft">
                  B748
                            </div>
                            <div>
                  <img src="dhl.png" class="image">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product span3">
                <div class="stand">
                  Stand 101
                </div>
                            <span class="apron">West Apron</span>
                            <div class="aircraft">
                  B748
                            </div>
                            <div>
                  <img src="dhl.png" class="image">
                </div>
              </div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicking on the button, the `<form>` will submit itself. You should capture and prevent that event.

Inside the `$(document).ready()` function, add:

```js
$('#standsearch').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent the `<form>` from ever being submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason, when I preview the page using a Web Server it works perfectly how I want it to but when I try it on an actual site the button to submit doesn’t work.

Comment: Figured it out now, thanks so much for your answer!